# What is "this" when in the callback of setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, this

Apologies for the newbie question, but consider this code

```
function Greeter( name) { this.name = name; }

Greeter.prototype.delayed_greet = function() { 
  setTimeout( function cb() { 
    console.log(' Hello ' + this.name); 
  }, 500); 
};

Greeter.prototype.greet = function() { 
    console.log(' Hello ' + this.name); 
}

const greeter = new Greeter(' World');

greeter.delayed_greet(); // will print "Hello undefined"
greeter.greet(); // will print "Hello World"
```

So in the `delayed_greet` method, what does `this` refer to when it's nested inside the `setTimeout`? It's obviously not referring to the `greeter` object otherwise it would work.

Comment: That depends on the context, but in a browser, it's most likely `window`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @adeneo, can you elaborate why `setTimeout` has this as the `window` or `global` object?

Comment: Where is the `DelayedGreeter` constructor? That code will give an error as it stands.

Comment: That was a typo on my part @Andy, I fixed it now.

Comment: Remember too in the constructor: `this.name = name;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` is generally defined as `window.setTimeout` in browsers, and can be called as just `setTimeout` because it's available in the global scope.

That also means the context, and `this` value, is always `window`, unless another `this` value is explicitly set.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) says

> Code executed by `setTimeout()` is called from an execution context
>   separate from the function from which setTimeout was called.
>
> The usual rules for setting the `this` keyword for the called function
>   apply, and if you have not set `this` in the call or with bind, it
>   will default to the global (or window) object in non–strict mode, or
>   be undefined in strict mode.
>
> It will not be the same as the `this` value for the function that
>   called setTimeout.

MDN also outlines a number of ways to solve the "this-problem" in `setTimeout`.
Personally I think I would just take the easy way out, and use a variable

```
Greeter.prototype.delayed_greet = function() { 
   var that = this;

   setTimeout( function cb() { 
       console.log(' Hello ' + that.name); 
   }, 500); 
};
```

Another option would be an arrow function, as they keep the surrounding context and don't create their own context.

```js
var o = { 
    fn () { 
        setTimeout( () => { console.log(this) }, 500) 
    } 
}

var o2 = { 
    fn () { 
        setTimeout( function() { 
            console.log(this === window) 
        }, 1000) 
    } 
}

o.fn();  // fn()              ---  arrow function
o2.fn(); // true, is window   ---  regular function
```

Comment: If ES6, [a fat arrow would make sense too](https://jsfiddle.net/52ofc0ca/) - one less variable. (edit: I see that was covered in the MDN documentation).

Comment: Yes, arrow functons are "special", they keep the surrounding context, even in timers -> https://jsfiddle.net/j5qsvs9t/2/

Comment: Is there a specific reason you didn't add a `bind` example ?

Comment: @Taurus - no, not really, but that's an option as well. All modern browsers also supports additional arguments being passed to `setTimeout`, so one can do `setTimeout( (that) => {}, 1000, this )` as well to pass in some value etc.

Comment: @adeneo I just asked because `bind` does get omitted a lot in questions it could be applied to positively (you did mention `bind`, but i wondered why there wasn't an example. Thanks for the extra parameter reminder :) had forgotten about them, but is browser-support for these context parameters really that great ?

Comment: @adeneo Ahaa, now i get what you meant.

Comment: @adeneo You could achieve the same result with `var x = (that) => {console.log(that);};
setTimeout(function() {x(20);} , 1000);`, right ?